# gdb : address range mappings

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, coredump

I am analyzing this core dump

```
   Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    0xb7fff424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
    (gdb) where
    #0  0xb7fff424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
    #1  0x0050cd71 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
    #2  0x0050e64a in abort () at abort.c:92
    #3  0x08083b3b in ?? ()
    #4  0x08095461 in ?? ()
    #5  0x0808bdea in ?? ()
    #6  0x0808c4e2 in ?? ()
    #7  0x080b683b in ?? ()
    #8  0x0805d845 in ?? ()
    #9  0x08083eb6 in ?? ()
    #10 0x08061402 in ?? ()
    #11 0x004f8cc6 in __libc_start_main (main=0x805f390, argc=15, ubp_av=0xbfffef64, init=0x825e220, fini=0x825e210, 
        rtld_fini=0x4cb220 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xbfffef5c) at libc-start.c:226
    #12 0x0804e5d1 in ?? ()
```

I'm not able to know which function `??` maps to OR for instance `#10 0x08061402 in ?? ()` 
falls in which address range ...

Please help me debug this.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has no debugging symbols. Recompile it with `-g`. Make sure you haven't stripped your executable, e.g. by passing `-s` to the linker.

Comment: the fields marked ?? are not from my program which is already compiled with -g : these symbols come form share libraries /// which one ?? I want to know ?? so that I can install the debuginfo

Comment: @user794080: then one of the libraries your program is using is missing its debugging symbols.

Comment: @user: no, they are from your program.

Answer (score 2):

Even though @user794080 didn't say so, it appears exceedingly likely that his program is a 32-bit linux executable.

There are two possible reasons (I can think of) for symbols from main executable (and all symbols in the stack trace in the range [0x08040000,0x08100000) *are* from the main executable) not to show up.

1. The main executable has in fact been stripped (this is the same as
   ninjalj's answer), and often happens when '-s' is passed into the linker, perhaps inadvertently.
2. The executable has been compiled with a new(er) GCC, but is being debugged by an old(er) GDB, which chokes on some newer dwarf construct (there should be a warning from GDB about that).

Answer (score 0):

To know what libraries are mapped into the application, record a pid of you program, stopped in gdb and run in other console

```
cat /proc/$pid/maps
```

wher $pid is the pid of stopped process. Format of the maps file is described at http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc - starting from *"/proc/[number]/maps
A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and their access permissions."*

Also, if your OS don't use a ASLR (address space layout randomization) or it is disabled for your program, you can use

```
ldd ./program
```

to list linked libraries and their memory ranges. But if ASLR is turned on, you will be not able to get real memory mapping ranges info, as it will change for each run of program. But even then you will know, what libraries are linked in dynamically and install a debuginfo for them.

Comment: 0x08xxx is the executable. 0x004xxx are libraries. I thin the OP isn't running exec-shield nor PAX.

Comment: it can be a static library too.

Comment: ah, yes, though I wouldn't expect `__libc_start_main` to call it directly.

Comment: 9: 0x08083eb6 and 10: 0x08061402 can be from main and static lib, they are far enough.

Answer (score 0):

The stack might be corrupted.  The "??" can happen if the return address on the stack has been overwritten by, for example, a buffer overflow.